# Redirect another page after successful form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I need to redirect another page after successful form submission. I'm new in JavaScript. I need to know how to do the right way. Redirect to a other page after successful form submission through AJAX. first this code have a form submission after redirect to another page.

I'm Programming with php/wordpress.

php/html code:

```
<form id="alecaddd-testimonial-form" action="#" method="post" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">

  <div class="field-container">
    <input type="text" class="field-input" placeholder="Adult" id="name" name="name" required>
    <small class="field-msg error" data-error="invalidName">Your Name is Required</small>
  </div>

  <div class="field-container">
    <input type="text" class="field-input" placeholder="infant" id="infant" name="infant" required>
    <small class="field-msg error" data-error="invalidName">Your Name is Required</small>
  </div>


  <div class="field-container">
    <input type="email" class="field-input" placeholder="Child" id="email" name="email" required>
    <small class="field-msg error" data-error="invalidEmail">The Email address is not valid</small>
  </div>

  <div class="field-container">
    <input type="date" class="field-input" placeholder="date" id="date" name="date" required>
    <small class="field-msg error" data-error="invalidEmail">The Email address is not valid</small>
  </div>



  <div class="field-container">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="field-input" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
    <small class="field-msg error" data-error="invalidMessage">A Message is Required</small>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field-container">
    <div>
      <a href="order.php?id=102" class="btn btn-success">
            <button type="stubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-sunset-form">BOOK NOW</button>
        </div>
        </a>
    <small class="field-msg js-form-submission">Submission in process, please wait&hellip;</small>
    <small class="field-msg success js-form-success">Message Successfully submitted, thank you!</small>
    <small class="field-msg error js-form-error">There was a problem with the Contact Form, please try again!</small>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit_testimonial">
  <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce("testimonial-nonce") ?>">

</form>
```

Javascript:-

```
 ! function o(n, i, u) {
function c(r, e) {
    if (!i[r]) {
        if (!n[r]) {
            var t = "function" == typeof require && require;
            if (!e && t) return t(r, !0);
            if (l) return l(r, !0);
            var s = new Error("Cannot find module '" + r + "'");
            throw s.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", s
        }
        var a = i[r] = {
            exports: {}
        };
        n[r][0].call(a.exports, function(e) {
            return c(n[r][1][e] || e)
        }, a, a.exports, o, n, i, u)
    }
    return i[r].exports
}
for (var l = "function" == typeof require && require, e = 0; e < u.length; e++) c(u[e]);
return c }({
1: [function(e, r, t) {
    "use strict";

    function o() {
        document.querySelectorAll(".field-msg").forEach(function(e) {
            return e.classList.remove("show")
        })
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
        var a = document.getElementById("alecaddd-testimonial-form");
        a.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(), o();
            var r = {
                name: a.querySelector('[name="name"]').value,
                email: a.querySelector('[name="email"]').value,
                message: a.querySelector('[name="message"]').value,
                nonce: a.querySelector('[name="nonce"]').value
            };
            if (r.name)

                
                if (/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(String(r.email).toLowerCase()))
                    if (r.message) {
                        var t = a.dataset.url,
                            s = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(a));
                        a.querySelector(".js-form-submission").classList.add("show"), fetch(t, {
                            method: "POST",
                            body: s
                        }).then(function(e) {
                            return e.json()
                        }).then(function(e) {
                            window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
                        }).catch(function(e) {
                            o(), a.querySelector(".js-form-error").classList.add("show")
                        }).then(function(e) {
                            o(), 0 !== e && "error" !== e.status ? (a.querySelector(".js-form-success").classList.add("show"), a.reset()) : a.querySelector(".js-form-error").classList.add("show")   
                        })
                       
                    } else a.querySelector('[data-error="invalidMessage"]').classList.add("show");
            else a.querySelector('[data-error="invalidEmail"]').classList.add("show");
            else a.querySelector('[data-error="invalidName"]').classList.add("show")
        })
    })
}, {}] }, {}, [1]); //# sourceMappingURL=form.js.map
```

Any help, as always, is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `header("Location:http://www.google.com");`

with:

```
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
```

`header()` is a PHP function which means "before you send the response back to the client (browser), add the `Location:` header. This header tells chrome to redirect using a 301 or 302 status code. PHP code obviously won't work in Javascript.

Considering javascript ONLY happens in the browser there are no headers that need to be set. You can just tell javascript to directly navigate the current window to the URL you specify.

Comment: not working. i'm pasted this code correctly?  **window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'; **

Comment: i placed correct code but i don't know where to place exactly.

Comment: Delete THIS: https://i.imgur.com/C7QA0sl.jpg and Put THIS: `window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';`

Comment: Stop changing what I write

Comment: please look my qustion

Comment: I'm not sure, that's a lot of other code that could be wrong. I answered what you said specifically so you should mark it as answered and then ask a new question with the specific error.

Comment: Try to comment out this line with `//` like this:

Comment: `// return e.json()`

Comment: ok thanks, i know your code is right but i don't know where i would place the code, thanks for your help

Comment: i did it no luck.

Comment: Comment out the line I said and see if it works then

Comment: Oh well ok then.

Comment: i think you can help me, but you need to check whole code.

Comment: I'm modified php functions, it's working now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the page by using the below methods:

By using a meta tag in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://your-page-url.com" />
```

*Note that content="0;... is used for after how many seconds you need to redirect the page*

By using JavaScript:

```
window.location.href = "http://your-page-url.com";
```

By using jQuery:

```
$(location).attr('href', 'http://yourPage.com/');
```

Comment: first this code have a form submission after  redirect to another page

Comment: let me know which programming language using ?

Comment: I'm using php / wordpress

Comment: see for jquery and javascript you can select any one listed in above . if you are using php header("Location:https://www.formget.com/app/"); or java then you can use actionResponse.sendRedirect("page2.jsp");

Comment: ok for php you can use like below example : <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
if($name !=''&& $email !=''&& $contact !=''&& $address !='')
{
//  To redirect form on a particular page
header("Location:https://www.formget.com/app/");
}
else{
?><span><?php echo "Please fill all fields.....!!!!!!!!!!!!";?></span> <?php
}
}
?>

Comment: than you can redirect header in admin-ajax.php page inside success condition add header("Location:your-page-path");

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location.href`

Eg-

```
window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
```